# Javascript initially skipping over nested function and then comes back to it?

Tags: javascript

I'm experiencing some weird behavior in my code that I don't quite understand. I call a function, and inside that function there is another (anonymous) callback function it skips over and it goes to the end of the containing function, runs those lines, and then goes back into the callback function and runs those lines...  Anybody have some insight, what am I doing wrong? Is it doing this because the "relatedQuery" method isn't complete yet so it hasn't hit the callback function before it runs the rest of the containing function's lines? That's the only thing I can think of, but I'm also not very skilled at JS. I've added some console.log statements that will tell you the order in which lines are being hit.

```
//Call the mgmtPopupContent function
mgmtTractPopupBox.setContent(mgmtPopupContent);

function mgmtPopupContent(feature) {
    for (var attrb in feature.attributes) {
        if (attrb == "HabitatManagement.DBO.MgmtTracts.OBJECTID") {
            var OID = feature.attributes[attrb];
        }
    }
    var relatedQuery = new RelationshipQuery();
    relatedQuery.outFields = ["*"];
    relatedQuery.relationshipId = 0;
    relatedQuery.objectIds = [OID];
    //Get data year that the map view is set to and set the definition expression on the table
    viewYear = dom.byId("data-year").value;
    relatedQuery.definitionExpression = "YearTreated = " + viewYear;
    //Create table header that will go inside popup
    var content = '<table id="mgmtPopupTable1"><tr><th>Veg Mgmt Practice</th><th>Herbicide</th><th>Month</th><th>Year</th>\
                    <th>Implemented By</th><th>Funded By</th><th>Farm Bill Code</th></tr>';
    console.log("PRINTS FIRST");
    //Do query and get the attributes of each related record for the popup
    queryableMgmtTractFL.queryRelatedFeatures(relatedQuery, function (relatedRecords) {
        console.log("PRINTS THIRD");
        var fset = relatedRecords[OID].features;
        fset.forEach(function (feature) {
            var vegPractice = vegPName(feature.attributes.VegMgmtPractice);
            var herbicide = herbName(feature.attributes.Herbicide);
            var monthTreated = monthName(feature.attributes.MonthTreated);
            var yearTreated = feature.attributes.YearTreated;
            var impBy = impName(feature.attributes.ImplementedBy);
            var fundBy = fundName(feature.attributes.FundedBy);
            var fbc = feature.attributes.FarmBillCode;
            if (fundBy == "CRP" || fundBy == "CRP - CREP") {
                fbc = crpName(fbc);
            }
            else if (fundBy == "EQIP" || fundBy == "EQIP - RCPP") {
                fbc = eqipName(fbc);
            }
            else {
                fbc = "Not applicable";
            }
            row = '<tr><td>' + vegPractice + '</td><td>' + herbicide + '</td><td>' + monthTreated + '</td><td>' + yearTreated +
                '</td><td>' + impBy + '</td><td>' + fundBy + '</td><td>' + fbc + '</td></tr>';
            content = content + row;
        });
        content = content + '</table>';
    });
    console.log("PRINTS SECOND");
    return content;
}
```

Comment: try to come up with a minimal working snippet of code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: `queryRelatedFeatures` is asynchronous. So `console.log("PRINTS SECOND"); return content;` will always run before `console.log("PRINTS THIRD");`.  So you'll have to replace `return content;` to other code, something like `renderPopup( content );` after the forEach loop inside, sicne you have to wait for all the `queryRelatedFeatures()` calls to finish before you have all the data for the popup.

Comment: @Shilly - I think I need to put the asychronous function inside a promise maybe. The `content` variable gets altered by that function, and when I `return content` I need it to return the altered content instead of just the table header it's set to initially. Then inside my callback function, I think I need to add another `return content;` maybe, or return it with the promise I guess.

Comment: @MKF I've updated my answer. Promises would work as well, if you prefer promises over callbacks. The clue is that returning content immediately will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, you have to wait for the queries to finish before you can render the content. So something like:

```
let content = '<table id="mgmtPopupTable1"><tr><th>Veg Mgmt Practice</th><th>Herbicide</th><th>Month</th><th>Year</th>\
                <th>Implemented By</th><th>Funded By</th><th>Farm Bill Code</th></tr>';

const render_popup = function( content ) {
    document.querySelector( '#myPopup' ).innerHTML = content;
};

// Render only the headers to begin with.
render_popup( content );

queryableMgmtTractFL.queryRelatedFeatures(relatedQuery, function (relatedRecords) {
    var fset = relatedRecords[OID].features;
    fset.forEach(function (feature) {
        ...
    });
    // Rerender the popup, now headers And content.
    render_popup( content );
});
```